# Server roles command Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So recently i was trying to make server roles command in my discord bot, that will display all the roles present in server. I wanted to set them in a single column and not in rows. I wasn't able to do so. What changes can i make to show it in a single column [sorry if i wasnt able to make u understand correctly as i m a bit poor in english.] Any help is appreciated!

How I Want It To Be:

[image: How I Want It To Be]

How It Is:

[image]

My Current Code:

```py
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def roles(self, ctx):
        guild = ctx.guild
        roles = [role for role in guild.roles if role != ctx.guild.default_role]
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Server Roles", description=f" ".join([role.mention for role in roles]))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `\n` after you mention the role. This will start a new line in the embed.

Comment: i was going to ask how to use it but i just added it `description = f"`\n`".join...` and it worked thanks

Answer (score -2):

Changing joined string to `description=f"<br>".join([role.mention for role in roles])` would work if HTML escaping of the description was disabled.

Comment: it just added <br>@role1 <br> @role2 <br>@role3 to whole list sorry but using `\n` at place of `<br>` worked! still thanks

Comment: Interesting to see downvoting when OP used the raw idea in this answer to solve the issue.

Comment: @Niloct: I can't speak for the downvoters, but my guess: The question mark at the end of your answer makes this look like a question instead of a suggestion. Adding more explanation might help avoid such confusion—and, of course, is a best practice generally.